# Gradle: keyword `cvs` not allowed in java package name

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I tried to create an Android project with package `com.cvs.app` and Gradle is crashing during the build. If I remove `cvs` from the package - works fine.

*Note: `cvs` in the package works fine with Gradle version 3.2 and lower.*

1. Is there a list of prohibited keywords in Gradle?
2. Can I overcome this limitation somehow?

Comment: I can't believe Gradle would crash because of a perfectly legal package name you happened to choose.  But who knows?  Q: Please copy/paste the full error message from Android Studio into your post.

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5321

Comment: @Martheen yeah, you are right. Don't know how I missed it. Thanks! 
BTW, the issue seems fixed in 4.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Martheen mentioned in comments - this is a knows issue in Gradle -  github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5321

Seems to be resolved in 4.0.10

Comment: And 4.0 is already how many years old...? Time to upgrade :-)